# I can't make 2 column layout in css

Tags: html, css

Today I try to learn html and css. but when i try to make a 2 column layout in the body, i have a problem that i can't divide it into 2 parts even though i have given this code previously in the css section

```
.leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

.rightcolumn {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;

}
```

when I debug this html what happens is that the right column stays under the left, but doesn't move to the top on the right

I'm confused why something like this can happen even though I have given the width value to each column before
if you know the solution please help me

Comment: use display flex to row class : .row{ display: flex;}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add more css :

```
.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.rightcolumn {
   width: 25%;
   float: left;
   background-color: #ff9600;
   height: 50px;
}
```

exaple here: https://codepen.io/phm-tun-v/pen/rNJojbZ

Comment: @Irfanda Anugerah Is it ok ?

Comment: still got the same problem
https://codepen.io/suizo-zouis/pen/rNJoyaQ

Comment: you have another way ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/phm-tun-v/pen/OJQrpyp @Irfanda Anugerah Please try it ?

Comment: use display flex to row class : .row{  display: flex;}

Comment: Yes, i think you should use "display flex" here